# How to set an arabic locale in C++ using std::locale class?

Tags: c++, locale, arabic, windows-11

```cpp
#include <locale>
int main(){
    std::locale::global(std::locale("en_GB.utf8"));
}
```

From my reading this is the way to set a locale in my C++ program. But what string should I pass to the `std::locale()` constructor/object? if I want Arabic locale? Does passing "ar_AR.utf8" will work?

Meaning if I write:

```cpp
#include <locale>
int main(){
    std::locale::global(std::locale("ar_AR.utf8"));
}
```

Will this work? Because my plan is that to eventually write to a file. Bear in mind my current locale is "C".

I know this because I wrote

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
int main(){
    std::cout << std::locale().name() << std::endl;
}
```

and it prints `C`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
int main(){
    std::locale::global(std::locale("ar_AR.utf8"));
    std::cout << std::locale().name()<< std::endl;
}
```

It prints `ar_AR.utf8`.

Later I try like this.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
int main() {
    std::locale::global(std::locale("ar_AR.utf8"));
    std::cout << 'ت' << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

It prints `?`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
int main() {
    std::locale::global(std::locale("ar_AR.utf8"));
    std::cout << L"ت" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Using the string literal `L"ت"` and it prints a number `00007FF634AA0310`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
int main() {
    std::locale::global(std::locale("ar_AR.utf8"));
    std::cout << "ت" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

If not wide string without `L` it prints `?`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
int main() {
    std::locale::global(std::locale("ar_AR.utf8"));
    std::cout << 2.5 << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Tried to print `2.5` and `2.5` was printed.

Comment: what happened when you tried?

Comment: it printed "ar_AR.utf8" string but that does not mean it work..maybe i should try with `std::ofstream` or maybe `std::wofstream`

Comment: "but that does not mean it work." why not? The thing is, even if someone tells you "yes" you will still need to try and eventually it will work for you or not, we cannot know if it works for you before you try

Comment: Whether it works depends on whether your system supports that particular locale. If it doesn't support it at all, an exception will be thrown. Why don't you try to output something locale-dependent, like dates?

Comment: for example here https://godbolt.org/z/PK67Trsrc the locale is not available

Comment: i tried writing `std::cout<<'ت'<<std::endl;` but it prints `?`

Comment: If setting the locale throws no error, and printing the locale prints the expected, but using it fails then thats important information. Please edit your question to show the code you used

Comment: What happens if you make that "character" a string literal instead of character literal? UTF-8 is multi-byte. I'm not sure if what you're trying to do here will work as written.

Comment: it prints a number `00007FF634AA0310`

Comment: Not a _wide_ string... `std::cout` does not operate on those (although `std::wcout` would have worked). Like this: https://godbolt.org/z/zEq9oceaG -- and note that if you enable compiler warnings, it should have complained about the multi-character character constant.

Comment: it print `?`@paddy

Comment: In that case, I must ask: does your terminal use a font that supports this character?

Comment: What are your OS and compiler? Note that `'ت'` is always wrong, and `std::cout << L"ت" ` is always wrong too. `std::cout << "ت" << std::endl;` may or may not work as expected depending on your environment.

Comment: There are two issues here, one is encoding of [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), the other one is locale. Although both are related to (natural) language, they have little to do with each other. Locale controls e.g. the formatting of dates or decimal numbers. Try outputting 2.5 (I dimly recall Arabic uses comma as a decimal separator) to confirm that.

Comment: @n.m. windows microsoft 11 compiler i am not sure i just use  microsoft visual studio from microsoft website

Comment: @Friedrich `2.5` is printed out

Comment: because yesterday I downloaded and install keyboard support from microsoft for the arabic language

Comment: under Time & Language > Language & Region >Add a language

Comment: Works for me just fine on Windows 11 using MSVC 2022 (14.32.31326). Make sure your terminal is using UTF code page (65001). (note using `std::cout << "ت" << std::endl;`, your two other attempts are *totally wrong*, don't waste your time).

Comment: also in the project setting i use UNICODE as character set but in the source code i use the utf-8 character

Comment: @n.m. is it like this https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8 on how to set the terminal code page to UTF?

Comment: @Friedrich (1) The arabic locale on Windows does not use comma as a decimal separator. The French locale does. (2) The global locale is irrelevant. It does not affect `std::cout` at all. You need to imbue a locale to `std::cout` to change its locale (but this will not help render the correct Arabic character).

Comment: I have no idea, I am using Windows terminal app (not the obsolete console) I don't think I have ever modified the registry. I have 65001 as the default code page. Before mucking with the registry, try typing `chcp 65001` and enter in your terminal.

Comment: I think you *probably* need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window) instead but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it on the stream level by [`imbue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue).

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << 2.5 << '\n';
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale("de_DE.UTF-8"));
    std::cout << 2.5 << '\n';
}
```

```
2.5
2,5
```

Comment: i tried to make the compiler treat warning as error and it says warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u062A' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)

Comment: i tried setting the code page of the terminal to 65001 by typing `chcp 65001` in the `Developer Command Prompt` and then manually compile the source code named `main.cpp` by typing `cl /EHsc main.cpp` then the compiler still complaint that the current terminal's code page is still `1252` whereas i already set it to `65001`

Comment: @beginner That's an issue with Microsoft Windows Terminals. They have support for Unicode, but you must [explicitly enable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line) it. C++23 std::print will fix this, but it's not implemented yet. You can use the [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) with [fmt::print](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html) instead. Note that character encoding is something very different from locals!